# How to calculate $Card(Stab(\mathbb{N}^*_k) $?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let a group $G$ operate on a set $X$,
we define $\displaystyle{G_x=Stab(x)= \left\{ g \in G \mid g.x=x\right\}}$,and $Orb(x)=\left\{g.x \mid g \in G\right\}$.

moreover we have: $Card(Orb(x))=[G:G_x]. \quad(*)$

Now let $G=\mathcal{S}_n$ , $X=\mathcal{P_{n,k}}=$ set of all $k$-subsets formed from $\mathbb{N}^*_n=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$.

the action is defined by $(\sigma,A)\mapsto \sigma(A)$.
$Orb(\mathbb{N}^*_k)=\mathcal{P}_{n,k}\,$ .

if we apply $(*)$, we have $$Card(Orb(\mathbb{N}^*_k)=Card(\mathcal{P}_{n,k}\;)=\dfrac{|\mathcal{S}_n|}{Card(Stab(\mathbb{N}^*_k)}.$$
I know that $Card(Stab(\mathbb{N}^*_k)=k!(n-k)!$
but i can't prove it!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if $\sigma$ stabilizes $\mathbb N_k^*$ (that's a terrible notation by the way), then it induces a permutation of $\mathbb N_k^*$, and a permutation of $\mathbb N_n^*\setminus\mathbb N_k^* = \{k+1,...,n\}$.

So you get a morphism $Stab(\mathbb N_k^*)\to \mathcal S_n \times \mathcal S_{n-k}$ : to each $\sigma$ you associate the induced permutations.

It's easy to check that this is actually bijective, and so this tells you what $|Stab(\mathbb N_k^*)|$ is.

Comment: Thank you @Maxime. Honestly, i didn't understand your answer ! can you please elaborate ? i didn't understand why $\sigma$ induces a permutation ... and how to get the morphism  ?

Comment: If $\sigma (\mathbb N_k^*) = \mathbb N_k^*$, then you get a permutation of $\mathbb N_k^*$ given by, well, $\sigma_{\mid \mathbb N_k^*}$, the restriction, and similarly for $\{k+1,...,n\}$. (in the future, don't accept answers until you understand them, it goes against the purpose of accepting an answer)

Comment: Thank you again @Maxime, i think i should take a pause.